# Can we say 'She sat in front of me'?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, grammaticality-in-context

I don't know why the key answer in my book chose this sentence:

> She sat down **opposite** me and started talking to me.

Instead of

> She sat down **in front of** me and started talking to me.

The instruction is choosing which one between **opposite** and **in front of** that fits in the blank. It's a standalone sentence, by the way, taken from the exercises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*She sat down in front of me* would usually be used when the two people are in seats facing all the same way, as in a theatre or church, and the newcomer sits in the row in front of the speaker (so she would probably turn round if she wants to talk).